# AWS CloudFront SDK - testing if a file can be served

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a server app that can serve files from it's local file system. However before it does that it should check to see whether the file could instead be served from CloudFront and, if so, redirect there instead.

Not all the files on the server are not necessarily duplicated in the S3 bucket origin(s) associated with the CloudFront distribution, so there will be some cases where a redirect to CloudFront is inappropriate.

How can I query the CloudFront SDK to find out whether a redirect to that would be successful (and not return a 404 for example)?

I appreciate that I could query the contents of an associated S3 bucket origin instead, but ideally I'd like to get the result from CloudFront so that it can do all of it's caching and failover between multiple origins and origin groups and I don't really want to have to replicate all of that logic in my code!

I happen to be using the c# SDK, but happy to accept answers in any language, it's more the principals behind it that I'm interested in. Am I perhaps thinking about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was vastly overthinking this. Just making a http request with HEAD rather than GET and checking the response was 200 was all that was needed.